# Usage of "-" (dash) in a phrase?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Are dashes necessary in the following sentence:

> It happens all-too-frequently.

I saw this sentence somewhere else, but if I google the sentence, I only see that people are using without dashes:

> It happens all too frequently.

Which one is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are not dashes. Dashes are longer and look like this: —(em dash) and –(en dash).

Hyphens are shorter, like this: -. They're used, among other things, to join words in uncommon contexts, so the reader understands that the words are to be understood as components of a phrase.

In your example the adverb phrase *all too frequently* has its ordinary construction and it occurs in an ordinary context, following the clause it modifies. Consequently the phrase should **not** be hyphenated—joined with hyphens.

But if you wanted to use the same phrase in an unusual context you should hyphenate it—for instance, if you wanted to use the phrase as a noun denoting something that happens more often than you like

> Three more complaints about Fred? Add that to the **all-too-frequently** list, and maybe that alongside the absences and the missed deadlines will persuade Bob to get him transferred to another department.